# Database caching library for javascript recommendations

Tags: javascript, database, synchronization, datastore

I'm looking for a Javascript library which implements a client (browser) side cache or data-store, with functions for synching to a remote, relational, database. Has anyone used something like this, or have a recommendation for a good quality library?

Answer (score 2):

The Backbone Todo example uses a localStorage implementation:

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html

It's pretty straight forward.  You may have to use something more robust if you have a lot of data.  You're probably going to have to write you own API.  Could be a fun open source project.

Here's how to access files on the client: http://www.htmlfivewow.com/slide30